# リモート環境のディスクサイズ取得方法を知りたいです

Tags: windows, command-line

Windows のコマンドプロンプトについての質問です。
どなたか知っていたら教えてほしいのですが、例えば、リモート環境のCドライブのサイズを、簡単にコマンドプロンプトから調べる方法ってありますか？ (何かquery を投げればいい気がしてますが、方法がわかりません。。。)

状況を説明しますと、現在、リモート環境で仕事をすることが多いのですが、多数ユーザーがログインする環境のため、ディスクサイズが圧迫されることが多く、定期的にファイルを削除する必要があります。現状、人が定期的に環境に入って逐次確認しているのですが、可能であればそれをやめたいです。リモートデスクトップ接続せずに、ディスクサイズを知る方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

WMIが使える環境なら

```
wmic /node:"取得したいサーバー名" /user:Administrator権限をもつユーザー名 /password:パスワード logicaldisk where deviceid="C:" list brief
```

でCドライブの空き容量等が取得出来るかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

あらかじめ確認したいディスクを共有フォルダとして設定しておいた上で、クライアント側からは`dir`コマンドで使用状況をコマンドラインから確認できそうです。

[Windowsのdirコマンドで共有フォルダーの空き容量を調べる：Tech TIPS - ＠IT](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0408/14/news017.html)

Comment: なるほど。。。言われてみればフォルダの閲覧権限は、フォルダ毎に共有しないとつかないから、
仮にクエリでできたとしても、閲覧される側の共有設定は必須ってことですね。 回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 質問や回答に対する「注釈」は、回答ではなく「コメント」として投稿するようにお願いします (今回は勝手ながらこちらでコメントに変換させてもらいました)。

Comment: また、質問時とは別アカウントになっているようなので、意図せずアカウントが分かれてしまった場合には次のヘルプも参考にしてください。 - [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)